# Jqplot removing axis scalars(numbers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

How can I remove the axis scalars(numbers) in jqplot? Are there any better alternative jquery or js graph libraries? Thanks

Comment: Your chart won't be much good if users can't see what the points represent.

Comment: Well actually I wanna put something a trend graph like in google finance......Didn't find a good tool for that though

Comment: Even so: SOME numbers on the chart are necessary to give the trend a proper context. Failing to do so is careless at best and deceptive at worst.

Comment: Flotr2 is a good alternative for jqplot